# Passing system properties to tomcat managed webapp when started by another process

Tags: java, tomcat, startup

The startUp script of webapp is going to be executed by a standalone java management process. I understand that -D system properties can be set to CATALINA_OPTS in catalina.sh. So is the only way to pass system properties is for the java management process to go write into catalina.sh? I

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this should be possible, but dont have the exact answer.

If it can be passed in an ant task [like shown on this link](http://ptrthomas.wordpress.com/2006/03/25/how-to-start-and-stop-tomcat-from-ant/), I assume it should be able to call the

`org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap load()` passing in JVM args

```
<target name="tomcat-start">
    <java jar="${tomcat.home}/bin/bootstrap.jar" fork="true">
        <jvmarg value="-Dcatalina.home=${tomcat.home}"/>
    </java>
</target>

<target name="tomcat-stop">
    <java jar="${tomcat.home}/bin/bootstrap.jar" fork="true">
        <jvmarg value="-Dcatalina.home=${tomcat.home}"/>
        <arg line="stop"/>
    </java>
</target>
```